# Exception found trying to parseDouble

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to make an app to calculate CGPA. I have used my numeric data to save in Double variable type.

On executing, it showed

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>    error on my logcat.

It showed error on this segment of code:

```
 total_credit = Double.parseDouble(ch1.getText().toString()) + 
        Double.parseDouble(ch2.getText().toString()) + 
        Double.parseDouble(ch3.getText().toString()) + 
        Double.parseDouble(ch4.getText().toString()) + 
        Double.parseDouble(ch5.getText().toString()) + 
        Double.parseDouble(ch6.getText().toString());
```

I tried to handle the exception as :

```
try {
    total_credit = Double.parseDouble(...);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    total_credit = 0.0;
}
```

On executing now, error has been occured on same line and error is:

> ComponentInfo{com.example.aashish.cgpacalculator/com.example.aashish.cgpacalculator.calculator_page}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: Are you sure you are unable to read the value of total_credit AFTER the catch block ? is the app crashing ? If yes, then you are not handling some other exceptions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an **java.lang.NumberFormatException** and as the message suggest, the reason is that you are trying to parse or convert or a double something that is not(in your case an empty string)

## How can be fixed?

you can always verify if the widget is holding an empty string before doing any conversion

just by doing

```
if (myString.isEmpty()) {
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the texts are empty. Is not possible to say which one. Check all the values:

- ch1.getText()
- ch2.getText()
- ch3.getText()
- ch4.getText()
- ch5.getText()
- ch6.getText()

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ch1.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") || ch2.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") || ch3.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") || ch4.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") || ch5.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") || ch6.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
    // empty String
    }
    else{
    try {
            double number1 = Double.parseDouble(ch1.getText().toString().trim());
            double number2 = Double.parseDouble(ch2.getText().toString().trim());
            double number3 = Double.parseDouble(ch3.getText().toString().trim());
            double number4 = Double.parseDouble(ch4.getText().toString().trim());
            double number5 = Double.parseDouble(ch5.getText().toString().trim());
            double number6 = Double.parseDouble(ch6.getText().toString().trim());

        double total_credit = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5 + number6;

    } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether any text is empty or not for each and every control ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5, ch6.

You can use `TextUtils.isEmpty(ch1.getText())` which returns boolean.

Comment: Just figured out that i was trying to take text from edit text before it was filled and use it. The issue was solved after extracting text inside onClick().